# Code navigation in GoLand 2023.3.4 on macOS

Tags: macos, go, keyboard-shortcuts, goland

In `GoLand 2022.x.x` there were arrows in the toolbar to navigate through the code.

For example when you jump to some function definition, you could jump back with those arrows.

In `GoLand 2023.3.4` there are no such controls. Having custom defined keyboard shortcuts one cannot just navigate through code as it was before.

Does anyone know how to get those controls in a toolbar back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with the new GoLand UI I found out that it is possible to get old controls back by disabling the new appearance (requires GoLand restart) `GoLand -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior`:

[image: Disable new UI]

Then re-enable main toolbar `View -> Appearance -> Toolbar`

[image: re-enable new toolbar]

And it's back:

[image: Main toolbar with old controls]

Answer (score -1):

Could you please send a screenshot of how things looked like in 2022.x.x to illustrate what you're trying to achieve? I checked 2022.2.6, and for me, the functionality looks identical to 2023.3.4. The navigation is performed via a shortcut CMD+B in both versions.

You can download older versions via from here - https://www.jetbrains.com/go/download/other.html .

Comment: Older versions have some bugs I don't want to work around. I found the solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).